# TightVnc change theme when disconnected

Tags: tightvnc

Every now & then i use Tightvnc to connect to the desktop from the laptop(Windows 7)
The desktop pic on the (Windows 10) PC goes black as normal but then it loses the theme settings & creates a new unsaved theme with just one desktop picture (the one that was on at the time) I then have to go & select the theme i was using & delete this newly created "**unsaved theme**". 
i already tried  to change the configuration->server->Hide desktop wallpaper, but no work.
Any idea?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After last (features) updates in both PCs, Seems to be solved. specific after 2017-05 updates from Microsoft.!